# Disable automatic deploy on push on Azure Repo

Tags: azure, azure-devops, web-deployment, continuous-deployment

I'm using Azure DevOps repository for a .NET Core web API and it happens that when I push the code into the repository, the application is immediately published to an Azure App Service. Since I'm using Azure Pipelines to execute some checks before publishing it, I need to disable this automatic deployment done by the push operation, but I didn't figure out how to do it. Is there a way to do it?

By accessing the Kudu service at xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net I noticed that there's a folder under site/deployments/tool that contains two files:
- deploy.cmd
- deploymentCacheKey

If I manually remove them, they're automatically recreated once a push is done and the unwanted deployment operation happens.

I have other repositories that have the same folder but it's empty and when I push it remains empty and no unwanted deployment operation is done.

Do you have any suggestion about how to disable this behavior?

**Edit**
Added screenshots of continuous deployment trigger in the Release pipeline and the release history
[Continuous deployment triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRHUf.png)
[Release history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he6ed.png)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment#disable-continuous-deployment Is this what you need?

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT sorry if I didn't mention it, but I already tried to do the disconnection by following the documentation, but with no success

Comment: Do you check that the continuous deployment trigger is disabled in release.

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT which trigger do you mean? where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the Continuous deployment trigger is disabled in the lightning icon of Artifacts , as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the Continuous Deployment check is enabled on my release pipeline, where the artifacts in input are provided from a CI pipeline, but all the deployment steps are manual, so when a new CI build is done, a new release is created but not deployed, as it requires manual approval.

Comment: In addition to it, during my tries I've disabled the CI and Release pipeline, but the unwanted deployment on Azure App Service continued to be done, like it was fired from the Git repository or something around it.

Comment: Can you provide me with your trigger settings and release history as screenshots?

Comment: Sure, I've just added them to the question

Comment: The only reason I can think of right now is whether there are other release pipelines with the same artifact source that trigger cd. You can check this.